# Why is a column space a subspace of$\mathbb R^{(number\ \ of\ \ rows)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

For an $m\times n$ matrix  $A$, $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^M$.  Why is it $\mathbb R^M$ rather than $\mathbb R^N$?
I would think the column space would be a subspace of its number of columns rather than its number of rows.

Comment: That is false: a matrix is not a vector space. The *set* of all $m\times n$ matrices is a vector space.

Comment: Okay thank you.  So A is not a subspace of R^M, it is in R^M.  But I'm still confused as to why R^M rather than R^N.

Comment: That is also wrong: $A\in R^{mn}$ since it requires $mn$ coefficients.

Comment: Theorem: "The column space of an m x n matrix A is a subspace of R^m"

Comment: Ah! Isee what's confusing you. The column space is the subspace of $\mathbf R^m$ generated by the *column vectors* of the matrix, it is not the matrix itself.

Comment: Oh okay!  That helps a lot.  I'll have to re-familiarize myself with column spaces.  Thanks.

Comment: Because Each Column would have "m" elements in them. Hence the column space would be a subspace of R^m.